In LWC , event, event.target, event.target.value are undefined
I have a button that, when clicked, triggers another component. Before doing so it logs information about the event.
I am new to LWC. I couldn't find the solution in LWC reference guide.
<template for:each={animeData} for:item="anime">
    <div key={anime._id} class="Anime-Item">
        <div class="Title">
            <h1>{anime.title}</h1>
            <p class="Ranking">Id: {anime._id}</p>
            <p class="Ranking">Ranking: {anime.ranking}</p>
            <p class="Genres">Genres: {anime.genres}</p>
            <p class="Episodes">Episodes: {anime.episodes}</p>
            <p class="Has-Episode">Has Episode: {anime.hasEpisode}</p>
            <p class="Has-Ranking">Has Ranking: {anime.hasRanking}</p>
            <p class="Status">Status: {anime.status}</p>
            <p class="Type">Type: {anime.type}</p>
            <a class="Anime-Link" href={anime.link}>More Details</a>
            <button class="Book-Anime" id={anime._id} onclick={handleBookNow}>Book Now!</button>
        </div>
        <img class="Anime-Image" src={anime.image} alt="Anime Image">
    </div>
</template>


handleBookNow(event) {
    const animeId = event.target.id;
    console.log('Book Now button clicked for Anime ID:', animeId);
    this.bookNow(event);
}

bookNow(event) {
    const animeId = event.target.id;  // Consistent access to animeId
    console.log('Book Now action initiated for Anime ID:', animeId);
    this.isBook = true;
    this.isError = false;
}

connectedCallback() {
    this.getData();
}



You should use data attribute. I haven't run the code below, but it should work. If not, click on the link and do as in the example.
HTML:
<button class="Book-Anime" data-id={anime._id} onclick={handleBookNow}>Book Now!</button>

JS:
handleBookNow(event) {
    const animeId = event.target.dataset.id;
    console.log('Book Now button clicked for Anime ID:', animeId);
    this.bookNow(event);
}

Here you can find example

In case if you need provide value from one LWC component to another LWC component you can use Custom event.
firstComponent.html
<button class="Book-Anime" data-id={anime._id} onclick={handleBookNow}>Book Now!</button>

firstComponent.js
handleBookNow(event) {
    const animeId = event.target.dataset.id;
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('book', {detail: {animeId: animeId}}));
}

secondComponent.html
<c-first-component onbook={handleBook}></c-first-component>

secondComponent.js
handleBook(event) {
    let animeId = event.detail.animeId;
    console.log(animeId);
}

Documentation about Custom Event

It started working after few hours, Its really weird, I guess salesforce lwc issue.
For the same code

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
